# JavaScript won't work when loaded in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm teaching myself JS and html, so I think it might be a good idea to write a personal page. However, when I try to run my html file which includes a JS file, JS won't work. This is the head part where I included the JS file:

```
<head>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.js'></script>
    <title>Honeydukes</title>
</head>
```

I put all css files under a "css" folder and all js files are under a "js"folder. index.html is outside in the root directory. My js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#map').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '+=20px',
        width: '+=20px'
    });
});
$('#map').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        height: '-=20px',
        width: '-=20px'
    });
});
});
```

Am I missing something here? Can someone please take a look and enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: Did you remember to import jQuery via its own `<script>` tag?

Comment: You are missing jQuery. The jQuery source code must be loaded first before main.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the jQuery libs however you never include them in the code.

You can include them with the following line:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
```

Make sure to load jQuery BEFORE your js. Final code should be:

```
<head>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/main.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.js'></script>
    <title>Honeydukes</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Good catch! I was following the examples in Codeacademy and somehow their code works fine without including jQuery. I fixed this by referring through google CDN. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Codeacademy and many other's use jQuery built in since it's become "hand-in-hand" with js over the past few years.

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a reference to the JQuery file. without which this script will not run. you need to add a reference to the jquery file before your  `<script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.js'></script>`

you can refer it through a CDN or simply download it and copy it in your JS Folder.

your code should look something like this

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery<version>.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.js'></script>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I fixed it! Too bad I can only pick one correct answer...