# jQuery Code won't connect to search form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question pertains to [this question/post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387478/how-is-user-input-submitted-in-bootstrap-3-form/31389854?noredirect=1#comment51086582_31389854).
I have a search form that requires:
A: To pull the user input from the search form so our backend can provide the user with relevant search results.
B: We need to be able to insert default input into either, or both, search fields to enhance the user search experience. This should replace any placeholder values.

I have tried the following code in my main.js file (linked to the testpage.html):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn-search").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var x = $("#keyword").val("Nurse");
    var y = $("#location").val();
    $("#keyword").attr("value", x);
    $("#location").attr("value", y);
  });
});
```

I have also tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn-search").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#keyword").val(Nurse);
    $("#location").val();
  });
});
```

Do you know why this wouldn't work? I even tried to put this in the body of the page:

```
<script>
  $("#btn-search").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#keyword").val(Nurse);
    $("#location").val();
  });
</script>
```

Here's the html form:

```
<form class="form-inline no-margin center-block" action="http://www.somewebsite.com/unknown" method="POST" role="form">
                  <div class="row">
                    <center>
                    <fieldset>

                      <!-- Search input-->
                      <div class="form-group center-block">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <label class="sr-only" for="keyword">From:</label>
                          <input id="keyword" name="keyword" type="search" placeholder="Keyword" value="" class="form-control input-lg">

                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <!-- Search input-->
                      <div class="form-group center-block">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                          <label class="sr-only" for="location">From:</label>
                          <input id="location" name="location" type="search" placeholder="City, State, or Zip Code" class="form-control input-lg">

                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <input type="hidden" name="unknown" value="unknown">

                      <!-- Button -->
                      <div class="form-group center-block">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                          <button type="submit" id="btn-search" name="btn-search" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-tusaj">Search</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: can you show the html? where is `Nurse` defined? Any errors in your dev tools?

Comment: @atmd Done. You can now view the html form in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn-search").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#keyword").val("Nurse");
    $("#location").val("");
  });
});
```

`val()` requires a `String`. So using a string should solve the problem.

**Reference:** http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: @AbrarArique the code you posted still won't work. I tried doing <script>
                        `$( "btn-search" ).click(function() {
                          var textKeyword = $( this ).text("Nurse");
                          var textLocation = $( this ).text("Boston");
                          $( "keyword" ).val( textKeyword );
                          $( "location" ).val( textLocation );
                        });
                        </script> `
inline in the form and upon clicking the button, the first form field changes to Nurse but the second form field won't change to Boston.

Comment: @JBear Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/afq21rz9/  Your code should work like this as well.

Comment: Strange that it works so well in your fiddle but not in my webpage. Do you know whether bootstrap/initializr adds anything that messes up the main.js connection for jQuery in websites?

Comment: I got it working, yay! The issue had to do with loading my custom js code last, as per this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436335/javascript-wont-work-when-loaded-in-html    Thanks again for your help!